# Parsing a five part csv file into arrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, csv, parsing

I have a csv file with five parts;
ap_id,email_domain,email_user,first_name,last_name
with at least 150 rows.
I am trying to parse this into 5 separate arrays.
I have tried to use this code

```
NSMutableArray *apid = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *emailtwo = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *emailone = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *firstname = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *secondname = [NSMutableArray array];
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"2016 inter ind" ofType:@"csv"];
NSString *string = [ NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSCharacterSet *separator = [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet];
NSArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:separator ];
NSLog(@"array:%@",array);
for (NSString *row in array){
    NSLog(@"row;%@",row);
    NSArray* columns = [row componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    [apid addObject:columns[0]];
    [emailtwo addObject:columns[1]];
}
```

Get this error:

```
2017-05-31 16:54:29.582 mail sort app[46082:110639338] row;ap_id,email_domain,email_user,first_name,last_name
2017-05-31 16:54:29.582 mail sort app[46082:110639338] row;
2017-05-31 16:54:29.584 mail sort app[46082:110639338] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Yet I know there is entries for all rows in columns [1]

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: It's pretty clear that you're attempting to parse an empty row. Look at the 2nd line in your log- it just says `row;` indicating that there is nothing in `row[1]` yet you split it into columns (which there is only 1) and then you attempt to access the 2nd column with `columns[1]`. Check your full data source to make sure all lines have data if you are explicitly accessing the data in the row. My guess is that you have a row of column headers, then an empty row, and then your actual dataset starts.

Comment: here are the first four rows of the array

Comment: sorry took too long so here it is  here are the first four rows of the array  2017-05-31 19:09:58.975 mail sort app[47830:110967558] array:(
    "ap_id,email_domain,email_user,first_name,last_name",
    "",
    "021595,peak.org,urbanart,Maeona L,Urban",
    "",
    "021599,hotmail.com,audwann,Audrey,Wann",
    "",
    "021675,gmail.com,cluckcluck67147,Mrs Catherine,Everingham",
    "",
    
  if I just do column{0] I get all the ap_id added for each row like  ap_id 021595 021599 021675 etc in a column  so why doesn't the next item show up as a column of email_domains

Comment: I now see what you mean.  After the row with ap_id etc. there are two "" with nothing there.  So why when I ask for row column[0] do I get all the numbers with no problem.  but when I ask for the second column [1] I get a crash.  If I populate a text field with the "string" there are no gaps between row either.  Can't figure it out.  Any ideas?

Comment: So figured it out.  instead of using NSCharacterSet newLingeCharaterSet I used separatedByString:@"\n" and everything worked out fine

Comment: The reason it works for `column[0]` is because after doing `[row componentsSeparatedByString:@","]` on an empty string, you still have 1 component with an empty string in it. This component goes into `column[0]` and then nothing goes into `column[1]`. When you attempt to access the invalid `column[1]` your app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

When parsing the rows, it does not weed out blank rows before attempting to explicitly reference individual columns of that row. To make it safer, make sure that your dataset has the appropriate number of columns before attempting to parse.

```
for (NSString *row in array){
    NSLog(@"row;%@",row);
    NSArray* columns = [row componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    if(columns.count >= 5) { // make sure row has at least 5 columns before parsing
        [apid addObject:columns[0]];
        [emailtwo addObject:columns[1]];
        ...
    }
}
```

In your comments you mention that you changed the delimiter from `newlineCharacterSet` to `@"\n"` but you should still be wary with that approach. If a blank line ever makes its way into your dataset your app will crash.